# Typescript No Overloaded Match for this call styled(Row) of React styled component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having challenge understanding how to fix the typescript error on `styled(Row)` in the below React code

```
import { Col, Row } from 'react-grid-system';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const HeaderWrapper = styled(Row)`
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding: 4px 0;
`;
```

The error is:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(component: AnyStyledComponent): ThemedStyledFunction<any, any, any, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof Row' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyStyledComponent'.
      Type 'typeof Row' is not assignable to type 'StyledComponent<any, any, any, never>'.
        Type 'typeof Row' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(component: keyof IntrinsicElements | ComponentType<any>): ThemedStyledFunction<keyof IntrinsicElements | ComponentType<any>, any, {}, never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof Row' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof IntrinsicElements | ComponentType<any>'.
      Type 'typeof Row' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<any, any>'.
```

Hopefully, someone can help me fix this or guide me on where to look for the answer. thanks

Comment: Works fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-mcnulty-x96qzd?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @KonradLinkowski maybe he has different version

Comment: I tried to play around with my dependencies version such as making it the same with yours and still the error displays